# jQuery horizontal inView plug-in not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery

Here is my example code:

http://galenvinter.com/test-inview/

Basically, I'm going to build a horizontally scrolling set of images that need to lazy-load when in view. This works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated and I'll be sure to post them back to where I got the plug-in from: http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/

Thanks!

Comment: I see the images can be scrolled but only the scroller do not work in FF. Is that your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The horizontal scroll works in all modern web browsers for me.  However, the image that don't start in-view don't get loaded.

Comment: I see them getting loaded in FF 3.6.8 but scroll bar do not work.